# Set the value of a local variable equal to an env variable

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I have the below two files :

1) env-vars.sh

```
export MY_DATABASE=postgres
```

2) my-test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. $(pwd)/env-vars.sh
echo $MY_DATABASE

cat > $(pwd)/conf/my-vars.conf <<- "EOF"
MY_DATABASE=$MY_DATABASE
EOF
```

Now my second script is echoing the env variable in the env-vars.sh file properly and even creating the my-vars.conf file but the contents of this file are as below:

```
MY_DATABASE=$MY_DATABASE
```

I want the file my-vars.conf to have the value of the variable MY_DATABASE as postgres.
How do I assign the env variable value?

Comment: Alternatively to the solution posted in the answer, you can in your case also simply do a `echo "MY_DATABASE=$MY_DATABASE"  >"$PWD/conf/my-vars.conf"`. Of course, for the general case, a _here_-document is better (even though it is everything else then intuitive, that double quotes around the _here_-delimiter **prevent** variable substitution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control expansion with the quotes around the here document token:

```
# Shows "Hello, $(whoami)"
cat << "EOF"
Hello, $(whoami)
EOF

# Shows "Hello, myuser"
cat << EOF
Hello, $(whoami)
EOF
```

So just unquote `EOF` in your script.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I am a newbie in shell scripting. Can you please elaborate a bit on this? Also, my script had ' cat <<- "EOF" ' and yours 'cat << "EOF" ''. Whats the difference between <<- and << here? Both work for me.

Comment: String interpolation is not a safe way to create code that will reproduce an existing value.

Comment: @TAnna `<<-` allows you to indent the contents with tabs. You didn't have any indenting so I just used the regular `<<`

Answer (score 0):

To do this correctly, you need some additional support from your shell. Assuming you are using `bash`, you should use the following:

```
printf 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "$MY_DATABASE" >>  conf/my-vars.conf
```

The reason you need `%q` for this is to guard against a value of `MY_DATABASE` that doesn't allow simple interpolation to produce code that reproduces the value. Some examples:

```
$ MY_DATABASE="foo bar"
$ printf 'MY_DATABASE=%s\n' "$MY_DATABASE"
MY_DATABASE=foo bar
$ printf 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "$MY_DATABASE"
MY_DATABASE=foo\ bar
```

This might lead you to think you can just add quotes to the output. Wrong.

```
$ MY_DATABASE='foo" bar'
$ printf 'MY_DATABASE="%s"\n' "$MY_DATABASE"
MY_DATABASE="foo" bar"
$ printf 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "$MY_DATABASE"
MY_DATABASE=foo\"\ bar
```

It's better to write code that *can't* produce bad output than to write simpler code that relies on well-formed input.

---

If you need to combine `printf` with an additional `cat` command, the `printf` does not go inside the here document; both `cat` and `print` should write to the same output file.

```
printf 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "$MY_DATABASE" > conf/my-vars.conf
cat >> conf/my-vars.conf <<- "EOF"
SOME_OTHER_VAR="a different value"
EOF
```

Better yet, put both `printf` and `cat` inside a command group that shares a single output redirection.

```
{
  printf 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "$MY_DATABASE"
  cat <<- "EOF"
SOME_OTHER_VAR="a different value"
EOF
} > conf/my-vars.conf
```

Comment: Is this `.conf` file a shell script?

Comment: Mm, good question. If it's not, the same issues exist, but using `%q` wouldn't necessarily be a solution.

Comment: If I need to update this in my script, how do I do that? I updated the line just below cat as 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "$MY_DATABASE" but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to use `printf`: `%q` is a special placeholder that gets replaced with another argument to `printf`.

Comment: I updated it to printf 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "$MY_DATABASE", the result in the .conf file is printf 'MY_DATABASE=%q\n' "postgres" . I am new to shell scripting so apologies if this is a very trivial question.